# How does angularjs services work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building my first real world Angularjs application. Object Menus is created in services by following code of my boiler plate code

```
angular.module('mean.system').factory('Menus', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('admin/menu/:name', {
        name: '@name',
        defaultMenu: '@defaultMenu'
    });
}]);
```

How does this work as in all the turorials I have seen http calls are made by explicitly mentioning the url format and type of request like in following

```
phonecatServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('phones/:phoneId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{phoneId:'phones'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js: service vs provider vs factory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be fair to say that this is a question about how `$resource` works? If that is the case the best place to start is having a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) and the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d5a92d22502dac617351dd2bc1726025973c439a/src/ngResource/resource.js).

Againt this version of the source, when you invoke `$resource(....)` you are calling the internal [`resourceFactory`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d5a92d22502dac617351dd2bc1726025973c439a/src/ngResource/resource.js#L472) which is building the resource out of the parameters you have provided and some sensible defaults.

Answer (score 1):

For better explanation you could check [Angular.js $resource docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource) 
`Menus` factory works practically the same as `Phone`factory.
It is return `$resource` object by which you can call a `query` with `name` and `defaultMenu` params. For example:

```
// set menu and default params
var name = 'admin'
  , default = 'main';

Menus.query({
  name: name,
  defaultMenu: default
}, function(menu) {
   // process responce from the server
   // what it should return?
   $scope.menu = menu;
});
```